# Carousel not displaying image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a carousel that is not displaying the images upon loading the webpage for some reason. I am working in dream weaver and for some reason the JS function only kicks in after clicking on one of the arrow buttons. I feel like I need to force feed the function one image in order for it show upon loading the page but I am not sure how to do this. Thanks for the help!

Here is the HTML (I have the JS fucntion in the head tags):

```js
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
```

```html
    <script src="testcar.js"></script>
    <section class="carousel">
 <div class="slideshow-container">
    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://www.healthypawspetinsurance.com/Images/V3/DogAndPuppyInsurance/Dog_CTA_Desktop_HeroImage.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg?itok=FSzwbBoi" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://www.what-dog.net/Images/faces2/scroll001.jpg" style="width:80%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use a plugin https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slideshow/

Comment: @user2182349 Unfortunately, this is part of an assignment for school. Normally my professor is all for plugins but he doesn't want to see any for our site this time...and before I get swarmed, this is just for a tiny part of my site that I'm stuck on

Comment: if your professor told you to use dreamweaver, please tell him it's seriously outdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try loading your JS after the HTML.

Check out the difference here:

1. https://jsfiddle.net/vy9uwxhk/ - look at the console for the **error**. As it's not finding the appropriate HTML, the code execution stops and results in non-working of the carousel.
2. https://jsfiddle.net/6k92zvze/ - here the `<script>` is loaded after the HTML and as it finds the HTML, the execution is successful and the carousel works fine.

Hope this helps. Here's more [info on where to include your script tags](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/best-practice-where-to-include-your-script-tags).