# Reactstrap - Display local image on carousel

Tags: reactjs, carousel, reactstrap

I am trying to create a carousel with images that are stored in the directory of my react app. When I use the default example ones found here:

> https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Everything works fine. The problem is when I add my custom images.

```
import customImage from './images/customImage.jpg';
const items = [
  {
    src: {customImage}, //Not Working
    altText: 'Slide 1',
    caption: 'Slide 1'
  }, 
  {
    src: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800   %22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ba800aa20%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ba800aa20%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22247.3203125%22%20y%3D%22218.3%22%3ESecond%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E',
    altText: 'Slide 2',
    caption: 'Slide 2'
    //Working
  },
  {
    src: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ba800aa21%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ba800aa21%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22277%22%20y%3D%22218.3%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E',
    altText: 'Slide 3',
    caption: 'Slide 3'
    //Working
  }
];
```

The code for my carousel is as follows:

```
const slides = items.map((item) => {
  return (
    <CarouselItem
      className="trustedMechsCarousal"
      onExiting={this.onExiting}
      onExited={this.onExited}
      key={item.src}
    >
    <img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
    <CarouselCaption captionText={item.caption} captionHeader={item.caption} />
    </CarouselItem>
  );
});

return(
  <div className='TrustedMechs'>
    <div className='SectionTitle'><h1>Trusted Mechanics</h1></div>
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        next={this.next}
        previous={this.previous}
      >
      <CarouselIndicators items={items} activeIndex={activeIndex} onClickHandler={this.goToIndex} />
        {slides}
        <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={this.previous} />
        <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={this.next} />
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  </div
);
```

The link below is to a question that seams to have the same problem as me but was caused by the html not rendering the carousel. My carousel is rendering, just not showing the image.

> [Carousel not displaying image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972408/carousel-not-displaying-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you source an image like that, it looks inside of the public folder for the /images folder. 
[image]

Your code should work, provided the name of the file is correct, and it's in that location.
At least with apps started with a create-react-app foundation, it does

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly braces from "customImage" like this

> `const items = [
>     {
>       src: {customImage}, //Not Working
>       altText: 'Slide 1',
>       caption: 'Slide 1'
>     }, 
>     {
>   .....`

To:

> `const items = [
>     {
>       src: customImage, 
>       altText: 'Slide 1',
>       caption: 'Slide 1'
>     }, 
>     {.....`